# Using apex class as attribute type for component - Summer '14 IDE issue

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, ide, summer14

I have a component that gets an instance custom Apex Class as an attribute, ie:

```
<apex:component controller="ComponentController">
    <apex:attribute name="myAttr" assignTo="{!attr}" type="MyApexClass" />

</apex:component>
```

I also have this class:

```
public with sharing class MyApexClass{
    //lots of content
}
```

But, since I updated Eclipse to the latest version (Summer '14, API version 31) I get this error when I try to save the component (or a page on which the component is used): `Compilation error: Type is not visible: myapexclass`.

I've already tried making MyApexClass global, doing so does solve the problem, however, this is for managed package so I really want to avoid making anything global that doesn't logically have to be, especially because it does work if I use Eclipse for version 30.

Comment: Same problem here :-( But it's not connected to Eclipse as I can reproduce it within the Developer Console.

Comment: Yeah, I got the same error on the developer console too. However, changing the pages or the component through the normal web interface does seem to work...

Comment: I can't find the reference to this now, but it is a bug in the tooling API. If you can change Eclipse to use the metadata API instead, then you can bypass this.

Comment: seems like this should be closed since Eclipse IDE has been retired

Comment: I wouldn't mind at all if this question gets closed. :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it relates a tool that's been deprecated for several years

Answer (score -1):

Please Find the solution.

```
 <apex:attribute name="myAttr" assignTo="{!attr}" type="MyApexClass" />
```

In this line attribute type should be object then it would work fine
you can take reference from my code;

aura component

```html
<apex:component controller="ComponentController">

   <aura:attribute name="check" type="object" description="" access="public"/>
    <h1>"{!v.check.accountList[0].Name}"</h1>//showing data

</apex:component>
```

controller or helper

```js
    var wrapperList=response.getReturnValue();
    c.set("v.check",wrapperList)
```

//apex class

```java
public class Test {

public with sharing class wrapperList{

    @auraEnabled
        public List<Account> accountList;
       
    }

    @auraEnabled
    public static wrapperList containerofList(){
        wrapperList obj=new wrapperList();


      list<Account> aclist = new list<Account>();

        aclist = [Select id,name from account limit 20];

     obj.accountList=aclist;

     return obj;

    }
}
```